# Using async / await in .NET Portable Library project

Tags: c#, async-await, portable-class-library

This line

```
StorageFile photo = await cameraUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

gives me this error:

> Error CS0012
>   The type 'IAsyncOperation<>' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,

How to fix it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps you need to add a reference to "Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract" library, which was explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50959930/4329813

Comment: Look at the **Important** notice [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/cross-platform/cross-platform-development-with-the-portable-class-library)

Comment: @jsanalytics Thanks, man. Good catch! Anyway I am wondering to use async/await in this type of DLL. Is it possible at all?

Comment: AcademyofProgrammer the async and await keyword is actually a compiler service. Therefore, it requires the platform support. You can see this for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/12600602/744343
As @jsanalytics mentioned, for new development, you should do the .NET Standard instead of PCL

Comment: @jsanalytics I cannot incapsulate  `CameraCaptureUI` into .NET Standart DLL to use in WPF project. That is the issue. Any clue how to do it?

Comment: This is WPF why do you need a PCL or .net standard at all, just use a regular class library

Comment: Did you try the [async targeting pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`?

Comment: Just to be sure: are you trying to access an UWP API from WPF?